# failed with:FATAL Alert:BAD_CERTIFICATE - A corrupt or unuseable certificate was received

Tags: ssl-certificate, weblogic-10.x, weblogic11g

I am trying to invoke a https soap webserice from the application which is deployed in weblogic 10.3 and getting **Error in authenticate Failed to access the WSDL at: https://exlx-xxxx.xxx.xs2.******cloud.com/publicXXXXXXXXxCommonXXXIntegration/XXXIntegrationService?wsdl. It failed with:FATAL Alert:BAD_CERTIFICATE - A corrupt or unuseable certificate was received..**

chain of certificates downloaded from browser and imported to weblogic server.

[image]

1) i have added the chain of certificate to **\wlserver_10.3\server\lib\DemoTrust.jks** by using below commands

```
keytool -import -alias root1 -file D:\1.cer -keystore client-truststore.jks
keytool -import -alias intermideate1 -file D:\2.cer -keystore client-truststore.jks
keytool -import -alias intermideate2 -file D:\3.cer -keystore client-truststore.jks
```

the above one did not work

2) As next step i have imported the certificates to **\jdk160_29\jre\lib\security\cacerts** by keytool command. this did not work

3) i clubbed the chain(3) of certificates to one crt file and imported to **\jdk160_29\jre\lib\security\cacerts**. this did not work

4) i clubbed the chain(3) of certificates to one crt file and imported to **\wlserver_10.3\server\lib\DemoTrust.jks.** this did not work

for all the above 4 steps which i gave a try, the logs remains same

Below are the logs

] The system is vulnerable to security attacks, since it trusts certificates signed by the demo trusted CA.>
<28 Nov, 2016 8:55:00 PM IST>    
<28 Nov, 2016 8:55:00 PM IST>    
<28 Nov, 2016 8:55:00 PM IST>    
<28 Nov, 2016 8:55:00 PM IST>    
<28 Nov, 2016 8:55:00 PM IST>    
<28 Nov, 2016 8:55:00 PM IST>    
<28 Nov, 2016 8:55:00 PM IST>    
<28 Nov, 2016 8:55:00 PM IST>    
<28 Nov, 2016 8:55:00 PM IST>    
<28 Nov, 2016 8:55:00 PM IST>    
<28 Nov, 2016 8:55:00 PM IST>    
2016-11-28 20:55:01,320 INFO  IntgOSCLoadService:72 - Error in authenticate Failed to access the WSDL at: https://exlx-xxxx.xxx.xs2.******cloud.com/publicXXXXXXXXxCommonXXXIntegration/XXXIntegrationService?wsdl. It failed with:
        **FATAL Alert:BAD_CERTIFICATE - A corrupt or unuseable certificate was received..**

Please help me to overcome this issue,thanks